# System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not find file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filestream

I am using file upload control. But when I try to read uploaded file, it's looking for folder where project is created and giving error.
The code for this

```
 <input type="file" name="file" />
 <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        string FileName = file.FileName;
        if (file != null && file.Length != 0)
        {
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open);
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use the [CopyTo(Stream)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.copyto?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_IFormFile_CopyTo_System_IO_Stream_) method instead of using the `FileName` property Or better use the [OpenReadStream()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.openreadstream?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_IFormFile_OpenReadStream) method to get a readable stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to read the uploaded file using stream, you can use the following,

```
        string result;
        if (file != null && file.Length != 0)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
            {
               result = reader.ReadToEnd();  
            }
        }
```

Or, if you are trying to save the uploaded file somewhere in the server then you should use the CopyTo method like below example,

```
        var destinationPath= Path.GetTempFileName(); //Change this line to point to your actual destination
        using (var stream = new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` inside your form action. You can use razor `@using (Html.BeginForm())`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "YourController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Source code view sample [here](https://github.com/deanilvincent/FileUploadAspNetCore/blob/master/FileUploadAspNetCore/Views/Home/Index.cshtml)

And inside your controller, you can use a method controller like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    var uploadPath = Path.Combine(hostingEnv.WebRootPath, "uploadsfolder");

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```

Source code controller sample [here](https://github.com/deanilvincent/FileUploadAspNetCore/blob/bb3d6ded8156626769d899cca8f28a6dae850239/FileUploadAspNetCore/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L44)

This should work properly